# Supported devices 0. Google Play Publish

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

I published an application but google play shows me that 0 devices are compatible. I checked the Manifest but I don't know why.

I tried to change minsdk and targetsdk but the result is the same.

I need help please!

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ru.xsrv.PhotoHouse">
    android:versionCode="20"
    android:versionName="2.0.3"> 


    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19"
    />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <!-- push messages -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="ru.xsrv.PhotoHouse.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="ru.xsrv.PhotoHouse.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" android:required="false"/>
    <application
        android:name=".PhotoApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_photo_house"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:logo="@drawable/action_bar_icon"
        android:theme="@style/PhotoHouseGeneratedTheme"
        android:allowBackup="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.main.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/style_01_drawable_back" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: I am a little confused that you request permission BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE under manifest tag, as I recall you have to define a service with such permission, can you try removing it from manifest tag and do it like it is described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html)?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it comes from these lines

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" android:required="false"/>
```

Have you tried to remove them ?